# What is the PostInfo Meta Tag that appears in my ASP page?

Tags: html, asp-classic

I've got a tag that looks like this:

```
<meta name="postinfo" content="/scripts/postinfo.asp">
```

that's appeared in my default.asp in a classic ASP application.

What is it and can I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a meta tag used by the Microsoft Posting Acceptor.  You can find more info in [this readme file](http://www.prof2000.pt/users/softwareservidor/ntoptionpacknt4/pareadme.htm).  Hope this helps!

Comment: To my knowledge I'm not using this; what might have set this property?

Comment: That's interesting, an editor or installer you've used at some point must have automatically inserted it.  If you're sure you don't use that technology then it would be safe to remove that meta tag for sure.